# how can I pass variable i in linearSearch function?

Tags: c++

In this code I need to check index of the value-

Sample Input :

1

7

2 13 4 1 3 6 28

3

Sample Output :
4

#include 
using namespace std;

```
int linearSearch(int *arr, int n, int x)
{
    //Write your code here
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        int *arr = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            cin >> arr[i];
        }
        int val;
        cin >> val;
        cout << linearSearch(arr, n, val) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That ==> `int linearSearch(...` the return type `int` is useful for something. I'd use that to return.. an `int` from inside your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your array is not sorted simple linear traversal of array is what you can do:

```
int linearSearch(int *arr, int n, int x)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
       // if match found.
       if(arr[i] == x){
          return i;
       }
    }
    // if not match found
    return -1;
}
```